# Need to get the single column

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table

```
col1  col2  col3
----------------
6      ab   
2      cd    3
3      eg    6
7      hs    3
5      gh    4
6      kj    7
```

When I search with kj (`col2`) for this col3-7 is equals to col1-7 so "hs" need to add to tree(hs-kj) now col3-3 with col1-3 "eg" add to tree and then col3-6 with col1-6 so "ab" add to tree so output should be(ab-eg-hs-kj)

Please anyone answer for this query?

Comment: Could you please rephrase that in form of a question?

Comment: It is a question and with some perseverance it is decodable.

Comment: SQL is not great for recursive queries. Any problem with doing this in a loop?  And: How big is the table in reality?

Comment: Write it out in C# with GetById(), make sure there are indexes on col1 and col3 and see if your performance is acceptable.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Next time, I will perform 1024 bit encryption on questions and then post them here. People can have all the fun they want to have with it :)

Comment: Any particular reason you have two #6? What would be the rule that `ab` would be chosen over `kj` when following the link from `eg`?

Comment: no reason for #6, , i want a tree as parent and child but search starts from last col2 value

Comment: You call it a 'tree' but the sample only shows pushing to the front of a list. Are there any left/right rules?

Comment: if I get the filtered column then i will manage in the code( C# ) goal is to get the filtered 2nd column by comparing 3rd and 1st columns loop repeats till the start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `col1` is unique, this query will do it;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT m.col2, m.col3, 1 col4 FROM mytable m WHERE col2='kj'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT m.col2, m.col3, col4+1 col4 FROM mytable m JOIN cte ON m.col1 = cte.col3
)
SELECT col2 FROM cte ORDER BY col4
```

[An SQLfiddle sample where col1 is unique](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3c0d2/5).

Currently, `ab` and `kj` have the same value for `col1` which makes the selection of `ab` over `kj` unclear. If it's not a mistake, a clarification on the selection criteria is needed.